# List of Arrays intersect

Tags: php, arrays, array-intersect

I have some arrays called

$array[1], $array[2] etc.

$array[1] is something like array(1,2,3) and $array[2] is sth. like array(2,3,4) 
now I want to have alle numbers which are in all arrays.

I want to use

```
array_intersect($array[1],$array[2])
```

for this.

BUT I have maybe 2 or 3 or 4 of this array. Is it possible to create a string like

```
$list_of_array = $array[1],$array[2];
```

and make a

```
 $result = array_intersect($list_of_arrays)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such behaviour with variable amount of arrays, you can use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

```
$array_list = array($array[1],$array[2],$array[3]);
$intersect = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$aarray_list);
```

#### Test

```
$array_list = array(array(1,2,3), array(2,3,4,5), array(3,7,"a"));
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$array_list);
print_r($result);
```

Returns

```
Array ( [2] => 3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array):

As the name suggests, you can use this function to call a user function and apply it with the parameters in the given array:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$list_of_arrays);
```

Here, the first parameter is the name of the function callback, and second one is our array.

Assuming you have the `$array` filled with your input arrays, you can do:

```
$list_of_arrays = $array;
$result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $list_of_arrays);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 3
)
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/lYaFOFFx)